# Can't dynamically fetch currency in a LWC when pulling from a wired Apex method

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, javascript, wire, currencyisocode

I am new at LWC and trying to do something I thought was fairly simple, basically just using apex methods to query data, wiring them in javascript, building out an array of information, and passing them along to display as data tables (Since some of the fields I am querying are traversing across objects, I have the intermediary step of building a javascript array). One of the fields I am querying from my custom object is CurrencyISOCode, but when I fetch it in my wired method, I want to use that value to dynamically set my currency column to have typeAttribute: currencyCode: (Currency Code Here). This doesn't seem to be sticking though because this particular record I'm working with is GBP and I see it is continuing to use my org default, USD.

I guess I don't understand the order of events of when the wired methods are happening vs when the tracked array of columns is initializing. Can someone explain why my CurrencyISOCode is not being fetched for the column here? This is my javascript.

```js
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import getRelatedStoreSubscriptions from '@salesforce/apex/AccountSubscriptionViewerController.getRelatedStoreSubscriptions';

export default class AccountSubscriptionViewerLWC extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track relatedStoreSubs = [];
    currencyIsoCode;
    refreshTable;
    error;
    
    @wire(getRelatedStoreSubscriptions, {accId : '$recordId'}) wiredStores(result){
        this.refreshTable = result;
        if(result.data){
            //console.log('data:' + JSON.stringify(result.data));
            let flattenedData = [];
            result.data.forEach(element => {
                let row = {};
                row.Id = element.Id;
                row.Product = element.Product__r.Name;
                row.Quantity = element.Quantity__c;
                row.ResponsibleParty = element.Responsible_Party__r.Name;
                row.ActiveMRRAmount = element.Active_MRR_Amount__c;
                row.Status = element.Status__c;
                row.StatusReason = element.Status_Reason__c;
                flattenedData.push(row);

                this.currencyIsoCode = element.CurrencyISOCode;
            });
            this.relatedStoreSubs = flattenedData;
        } 
        if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
        }
    }

    @track relatedStoreColumns = [
        { label: 'Id', fieldName: 'Id' },   
        { label: 'Product', fieldName: 'Product' },
        { label: 'Quantity', fieldName: 'Quantity'},
        { label: 'Responsible Party', fieldName: 'ResponsibleParty'},
        { label: 'Active MRR Amount', fieldName: 'ActiveMRRAmount', type: 'currency', typeAttributes: {currencyCode: {fieldName: 'currencyIsoCode'},currencyDisplayAs: "code" }},
        { label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status'},
        { label: 'Status Reason', fieldName: 'StatusReason'}
        ];
}
```

Comment: You only have the one currency in the LWC, but get it from each element, meaning only the last element's idea of currency gets kept. Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: Can you [edit] to show the template too?

Answer (score 2):

When in columns definition you set a value for `fieldName`, it must be the name of a property of array's elements (a property of each row), using the name of a property of your class won't work. Moreover as Phil pointed out in the comment, in each iteration you're replacing those value, so `this.currencyIsoCode` will hold the value of the last record.
By the way, instead of pushing elements into an array inside a foreach, you could leverage [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that returns a new array with each element being the result of the callback function.

```js
if (result.data) {
    this.relatedStoreSubs = result.data.map((element) => {
        return {
            Id: element.Id,
            Product: element.Product__r.Name,
            Quantity: element.Quantity__c,
            ResponsibleParty: element.Responsible_Party__r.Name,
            ActiveMRRAmount: element.Active_MRR_Amount__c,
            Status: element.Status__c,
            StatusReason: element.Status_Reason__c,
            currencyIsoCode: element.CurrencyISOCode
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I dont know why I was making it a class variable, I figured since it was the same for all records it was ok to just fetch it once as a universal thing, but I see it makes more sense to fetch it per record even if it will never change.

Comment: @Chris You're welcome. Please consider to mark helpful answers provided to your questions as accepted, to benefit the whole community. [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) you can read why this is a good practice.